# Completely broken (unviewing-untouchable) android screen - (known) patternlock - no google account

Tags: touchscreen, usb-on-the-go, external-keyboard, pattern-lock

After my mobile screen fell I was asking if there was someway to draw my android lock pattern, I precise, pattern, NOT PIN, by using a keyboard, maybe typing corresponding numbers on the numpad...

Up to 80% and more of my android screen is completely black and full of cracks, with big regions of it completely unresponsive, which is far enough to cancel the pattern immission out while using the few responsive parts in touchscreen. I tried to blindly input the pattern with a usb mouse connected via OTG, but this is really really impractical, up to the point the mobile has started a very annoying song everytime I input an incorrect pattern and every few seconds the screen would dim cancelling out what am doing.

Google account was disconnected, as well as usb debugging mode which was deactivated.

I noticed keys like enter, spacebar, shift, and other buttons are operative on the screen when I use a keyboard, which would be perfect for my case. PS: Maybe there is a way to mirror the screen to a tv AND use the mouse at the same time? Or even some external mousePAD with a pen that I can use to PRECISELY draw the pattern and unlock the screen?

Thank you everybody,
Have a good day.

Comment: there is no other way than drawing pattern with usb mouse. do some exercise on another device until you got a feeling for doing it blind. once device is unlocked you should be able to connect a bluetooth mouse, enable usb-debugging and remote access device via usb with [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc)

Comment: also check [broken-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) tag wiki